# c# insert multiple objects into a DB at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a POST method that takes two parameters one is a userID and the other one is a list of permissions that will be added to the user.

the thing is that for each POST method I will be inserting a lot of permissions like this.

```
{
  "sysUserId": 0,
  "permissionsToAdd": [
    1,3,5,6,8,500,80,650 ...
  ]
}
```

The internal Object model is composed like this:

```
int SysUserId 
byte SubscriptionId 
short PermissionId 
bool IsInactive 
int ModifiedBy 
List<Short> PermissionsToAdd
```

What I have been doing is creating multiple objects each one with the required parameters just changing the permissionID(PermissionsToAdd is a list of shorts which I receive from the POST request).

```
public async Task <List<SysUserPermission>> SavePermissions(SysUserPermission obj)
    {

              var result =  db.Set<SysUserPermission>()

                for (int i = 0; i < obj.PermissionsToAdd.Count; i++)
                {
                    obj.PermissionId = obj.PermissionsToAdd[i];

                     await result.AddAsync(obj);
                }

    }
```

I can't seem to find a way to save all the objects at the same time.

I hope the question is clear enough, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AddRangeAsync()`. The documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addrangeasync?view=efcore-3.1).

So, the code should look like:

```
public async Task <List<SysUserPermission>> SavePermissions(SysUserPermission obj)
    {

              var result =  db.Set<SysUserPermission>()

                for (int i = 0; i < obj.PermissionsToAdd.Count; i++)
                {
                    obj.PermissionId = obj.PermissionsToAdd[i];
                }
              await result.AddRangeAsync(obj.PermissionsToAdd);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a product/package called [Z Entity Framework](https://entityframework-extensions.net/) that does this via a [Bulk Insert](https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-insert) function. The syntax is a single line in which you can add a list of records:

```
context.BulkInsert(listOfRecordsToAdd);
```

Using this is much faster than `AddRangeAsync(...)` when adding many records at once